# Nested views and controllers

Tags: angularjs

I need to make next hierarchy: I got several user roles in my app. The interface of my app consists of a top navbar with different tabs for each role. Each tab usually has master-detail view, where some entities are presented and the first entity is loaded by default.

Before struggling with authentication (I found some articles about http interceptors etc) I wonder how to do the most simple thing: navigation system.

For example, let's say that I hardcoded my user role and admin role is loaded by default. I have a cp.html file where the top navigation is. When I go to '/' route if the user is logged I should redirect him to cp.html with admin tabs. If the user isn't logged I should redirect him  to '/login' page.

This is example of cp.html:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#/desktop">Desktop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/companies">Companies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/users">Users</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-include src="include">
</div>
```

And this is home ('/') controller:

```
function homeController($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    if ($routeParams.tab) {
        $scope.include = '/templates/' + $routeParams.tab + '.html';
    } else {
        $scope.include = '/templates/companies.html';
    }
}
```

And the main app.js:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cp.html',
        controller: homeController
    })

    .when('/:tab', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cp.html',
        controller: homeController
    })
```

So here depending on :tab parameter I can include different .html templates. But how to deal with controllers? Let's say I want to go to companies tab. I want to have my navbar + companies content. If I click on companies tab the file is included but I stay at homeController. If I use ng-controller directive, then how can I get the id of company? In typical example we have /companies/:companyId route. But if I use this route in routeProvider then what should I put as templateUrl? Moreover, when I click on companies tab I don't change my url, only include companies.html.

I'm totally confused with nested views and routes in AngularJS. I don't want to use third party libraries though, trying to figure out by myself how to deal with this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), I think it's exactly what you are looking for. Try [their example app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) as well.

Comment: I'll try, but I just wanted to do it without libraries... anyway thanks!

Comment: @Victor look at this jsfiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/joakimbeng/bPruQ/ in an attempt to load controller dynamically, It's inspired by the ng-view directive. May be it's something you can use?